# How can I add a title and change other plot aesthetics for an UpSet plot in python?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, upsetplot

I have installed and imported the following (using Google Colab):

```
!pip install upsetplot

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import upsetplot
from upsetplot import generate_data, plot
from upsetplot import UpSet
from upsetplot import from_contents
```

Versions:

- Python 3.8.16
- Numpy version: 1.21.6
- Pandas version: 1.3.5
- matplotlib version: 3.2.2
- upsetplot 0.8.0

...and defined a plot colour:

```
plot_colour = "#4F84B9"
```

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'File':['File_1', 'File_2', 'File_3'], 
                   'A':[1,1,0],
                   'B':[0,1,1],
                   'C':[1,0,1]})
```

[image: view of dataframe]

I re-shape it to prepare it for an UpSet plot:

```
files_labelled_A = set(df.loc[df["A"]==1, "File"])
files_labelled_B = set(df.loc[df["B"]==1, "File"])
files_labelled_C = set(df.loc[df["C"]==1, "File"])

contents = {'A': files_labelled_A,
            'B': files_labelled_B,
            'C': files_labelled_C}

from_contents(contents)
```

[image: view of updated data]

I create and view the UpSet plot successfully:

```
plt = UpSet(from_contents(contents), 
            subset_size='count', 
            facecolor=plot_colour).plot()
```

[image: view of UpSet plot]

How do I add a title and change other plot aesthetics as I usually do with matplotlib plots? When I try adding:

```
plt.title('my title here')
```

I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'title'

I've found some guidance at https://upsetplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/plot_sizing.html which creates the plot using a different method:

```
example = generate_counts()
print(example)

plot(example)
plt.suptitle('Defaults')
plt.show()
```

...and then successfully modifies the aesthetics in the typical matplotlib way, e.g.:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3))
plot(example, fig=fig, element_size=None)
plt.suptitle('Setting figsize explicitly')
plt.show()
```

...but I can't follow this same approach as I don't know how the 'example' data was created using generate_counts(). I don't know how to use this same approach with my data.

Can anyone help me to figure out either how to:

(1) use the approach that uses generate_counts(), or
(2) modify my approach so that I can change the matplotlib aesthetics (for example adding a title)?

Full code examples using my data would be appreciated, rather than just descriptions of what to do.

Comment: Thank you for the nicely formatted and reproducible question, rare enough to recognize it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shadowing the `plt` module, instead use:

```
d = UpSet(from_contents(contents), 
          subset_size='count', 
          facecolor=plot_colour).plot()
```

Which assigns to `d` (not `plt`!) a dictionary with the axes:

```
{'matrix': <AxesSubplot: >,
 'shading': <AxesSubplot: >,
 'totals': <AxesSubplot: >,
 'intersections': <AxesSubplot: ylabel='Intersection size'>}
```

You can then still use `plt`, but also access the axes with:

```
plt.title('my title here')
d['totals'].set_title('TITLE')
```

[image]

Comment: Adding plt.title('my title here') still gives the same error message "AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'title'". Adding d['totals'].set_title('TITLE') added "Text(0.5, 1.0, 'TITLE')" at the top of the plot. In both cases I add the title statement after the d= statement, like this:

d = UpSet(from_contents(contents), 
            subset_size='count', 
            facecolor=plot_colour).plot()
plt.title('my title here')

Is that right?

Comment: @code_to_joy restart your interpreter, you had overwritten the `plt` from `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Comment: Ah yes! I've restarted the run time and rerun everything with the new d name for the upset plot, and added a semi-colon after the last statement and the titles appear as in your example. Thank you so much! Your next coffee is on me :)